# String to Columns SQL - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, string, postgresql

This problem is giving me a headache. I have a column in PostgreSQL that is a string:

Example:
bp**Apx14**L**1**0**3**

The characters have always the same structure, the first two letters meaning one thing, etc.

So the output should be into columns:

[image: Output]

I can't figure it out, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `substring()` function:

```
select substring(the_col, 1, 2) as a,
       substring(the_col, 3, 5) as b,
       substring(the_col, 8, 1) as c,
       substring(the_col, 9, 1) as d,
       substring(the_col, 10, 1) as e,
       substring(the_col, 11, 1) as f
from the_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Another form of `substring()`

```
substring(string FROM start_position for length)

SELECT SUBSTRING(column_name FROM 1 FOR 2) a, 
   SUBSTRING(column_name FROM 3 FOR 5) b, 
   SUBSTRING(column_name FROM 8 FOR 1) c, 
   SUBSTRING(column_name FROM 9 FOR 1) d, 
   SUBSTRING(column_name FROM 10 FOR 1) e, 
   SUBSTRING(column_name FROM 11 FOR 1) f 
from your_table name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need regex in your substrings you could:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(A,B,C,D,E,F)
VALUES (
    substring('bpApx14L103' from '^[a-z]{2}'), 
    substring('bpApx14L103', 3, 5) 
    [...]
);
```

Of course the same works for selects,